# VBA macro multiplying column with outside cell, if certain criteria is met

Tags: vba, excel

please help me to solve the riddle.
Say I have 2 columns: 
one is with currency symbols(USD, GBP, EUR)
second is with different amounts.

What I need is to convert GBP and EUR to USD by multiplying them with F/X rate stored in other excel file and keep USD if the amount is in USD.

So far, I have done something like this:

```
Dim wk As Workbook
Set wk = Workbooks.Open("....\....xlsx")
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = wk.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
wk.Activate
sh.Select
If currency = "GBP" Then
    result = .Range("N:N") * sh.Range("A1")
    ElseIf currency = "EUR" Then
    result = .Range("N:N") * sh.Range("A2")
    Else currency = "USD" Then
    result = .Range("N:N") 
    End If
```

I guess I can do it with some loop but I am not very experienced in VBA, this came to me accidentally.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in VBA as opposed to using regular Excel formulas?

Comment: Hi there, this will be used later in Python... which reminds me that I can use that FX/rate variables as a scanner and to postpone VBA learning

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without VBA by just creating a table that houses your currency tickers (USD, EUR, GBP) matched with their corresponding conversion rates to USD. From there you can use a `VLOOKUP` in your raw data to extract the conversion, and simply multiply that by the amount in local currency to reach the USD equivalent.

> =VLOOKUP(E3,A:B,2,0)*F3

Where E3 is the currency to be converted, A:B is your table array (database), & F3 is the amount in local currency. Auto-fill the equation down your raw data to populate all conversions.

[image]

You can also nest this in a `IFERROR` to produce a message about any currencies that are not already stored in your database.

> IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3,A:B,2,0)*F3,"Currency Not in DB")

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! The matter is that I've already wrote a VBA macros which does many tasks and that is the only one that left me before enter the file as a database and further elaborate the data

Comment: Well one way is to incorporate this VLOOKUP and **filldown** to last row. Then copy/paste range as text